# In AutoCompleteTextView, is there a way to use the act of selecting a suggestion as a means of pressing "enter" to submit the sugggestion

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView, it gives a list of suggestions like it should, when you type something into the TextView. However, when you select the suggestion, you still have to hit Enter to not only remove the keyboard from the screen but to submit the suggestion that you chose. I'm trying to remove this extra step of hitting Enter because users aren't making the connection in my application that they have to hit enter key after they select the suggestion in the TextView. Any suggestions/help?

Here is what I've got that was suggested but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
element_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.element_bullet);
    //Get the string array of the radionuclide names that will auto complete.
    radionuclideNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.radionuclide_names);
    //Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout.
    radionuclideTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.radionuclide_autocomplete);
    //Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, radionuclideNames);
    //Apply the adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView.
    radionuclideTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Listen for when enter is pressed.
    radionuclideTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
            switch(parent.getId())
            {
            case R.id.radionuclide_autocomplete:
                element_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.selectedbulletstate);
                break;
            }
        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
          //TODO:
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
auto.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(auto.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

> ...but to submit the suggestion that you chose

The drop down should close automatically when you select one of the options.

Comment: Yes! this one worked, though I had just found it elsewhere (the other answer led me in the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you have such a thing, use

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
          //TODO:
        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
          //TODO:
        }
    });
```

Comment: How exactly would you implement that? I'm trying to use it and its not really doing anything for me.